# return multiple values from PHP to JS function (AJAX/SQL)

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

I want to have something like a small search engine for the FAQ section on my website. All it does is search the SLQ_DB for the term upon pressing a button.

I want to output the question and the answers in two seperate divs. Therefore I have $data and $data1 which belong to the divs.

```
$('input#name-submit').on('click',function()
{
    var name = $('input#name').val();
    //alert(name);
    if($.trim(name) != "")
    {
        $.post('ajax/name.php',{name:name},function(data, data1)
            {
                $('div#name-data').html(data);
                alert(answer);
                $('div#name-data1').html(data1);

            });
    }
});
```

But when I hit enter the second div shows "success". But the first one has data and data1 in it. When I write function(data1, data) in the js file, the data1 has all the information, and data is just "success".

What's happening here?

Comment: return a json string from your php and then parse that string in the javascript.  There are surely hundreds of pre-existing pages on this site that describe how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `echo` function in PHP outputs the content of a variable to the response body. This body is a "string" that your web application receives.

Let's say you have a code like this:

```
<?php
$var1 = "hello";
$var2 = "world";
echo $var1;
echo $var2;
?>
```

The resulting response body will look like this: `helloworld`.

Now let's say this is your JS code:

```
$.post('ajax/name.php',{name:name},function(data) {
    console.log(data); // "helloworld"
});
```

jQuery will pass the response body to the data variable, which now contains `heloworld`.

You need to somehow separate the individual variables inside the response body, e.g. using JSON.

First step is to encode the data on the server, that's as simple as that:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(["var1"=>$var1, "var2"=>$var2]);
?>
```

This will create a response body that looks like this: `{"var1":"hello","var2":"world"}`.

The next logical step is to decode this JSON using JavaScript:

```
$.post('ajax/name.php',{name:name},function(data) {
    var res = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(res.var1); // "hello"
    console.log(res.var2); // "world"
});
```